# Removing unneeded zeroes

Tags: java, android

How to delete zeroes in java (android) only if there is no non-zero value following them?
The value is stored in double and then later in string, so working on these variables would be best.

Example:
I have 12.50000
I want to have 12.5

Example2:
I have 65.4030
I want to have 65.403

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: You have a string: remove every 0 you find from the end, stop if non 0, and keep it if you find a point.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate of remove trailing zero, couldn't find it before asking the question.

Comment: Just convert your string to a number (float or double, in your case) and back to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String s = 12.50000;
s = s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```